# Where can I download public data set, especially shapefile?

Tags: shapefile, data

The places I know include:

- http://www.weogeo.com/
- http://geocommons.com/
- http://koordinates.com/

Any other suggestions?

Comment: For which location you want ?? For ex. with QGIS you will get Alaska data (http://hub.qgis.org/projects/quantum-gis/wiki/Download#72-Alaska)

Comment: My Area of interest is mainly in Asia and Global.

Comment: Any reasonable answer to this very broad question would be so long and take so long to write that it would be out of date before it was finished. Please feel welcome to inquire about *specific* forms of data.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

best source for global data imho is naturalearth:

http://www.naturalearthdata.com/

I collected a big list of public available data here:

http://desktopmapping.blogspot.co.at/2012/06/diverse-vektordaten.html (its in german, but you can just follow the links e.g. in the section global))

Answer (score 1):

The answer really depends on the area, and type of data you are interested in. 
One of the best locations to get POI and road data is from OSM. [Cloudmade](http://downloads.cloudmade.com/) provides this data in an easy to use manner.

***Update***
As Uffe has mentioned in a comment, the Cloudmade data is quite old. You can download the data from Geofabrik [here](http://download.geofabrik.de/)

Comment: Cloudmade provides hopelessly outdated versions from Dec 2011. Go directly to Geofabrik for updated versions.

Comment: @UffeKousgaard I did not know that the data was old. Thanks for letting me know.

Answer (score 1):

Check out http://www.gadm.org/ for shape-files of country administrative areas.